Flag Dataframe Rows Based on Multicolumn Match from Another Dataframe
This seems like it should be simple, but a parsimonious solution seems to be evading me.
I have two Pandas data frames, that both include columns, "A" and "B".
If a row contains a combination of "A" and "B" in df1 that is also in df2, I want to flag that value in df1.
Input df1:



A
B




1
9


2
8


3
7


4
6



Input df2:



A
B




2
8


4
6



Output df1:



A
B
Paired




1
9
False


2
8
True


3
7
False


4
6
True



Combinations of A and B are unique in df1 and df2, by the way.  There are no duplicate "keys".
Size of datasets is not such that speed is a primary consideration, but what is the most efficient way to do this?

I'm sorry about this; my tables render properly when I'm editing my drafts, but come out as raw text in my post.  What do I need to do to fix that?

You must have empty lines before and after the table to render properly (this is not the case with the preview, which makes it difficult to troubleshoot).

Thanks!! This is the 2nd time that has happened to me recently.

Use a merge with indicator=True and post-process the column:
out = (df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='Paired')
          .assign(Paired=lambda x: x['Paired'].eq('both'))
      )

# or, if you have many columns
cols = ['A', 'B']

out = (df1.merge(df2[cols], how='left', indicator='Paired')
          .assign(Paired=lambda x: x['Paired'].eq('both'))
      )

Or, if you want to modify df1 in place:
df1['Paired'] = (df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)['_merge']
                    .eq('both').values
                )

# if you have many columns
cols = ['A', 'B']
df1['Paired'] = (df1.merge(df2[cols], how='left', indicator=True)['_merge']
                    .eq('both').values
                )


NB. .values is required as the original index of df1 won't be kept if it is not a range index.
Output:
   A  B  Paired
0  1  9   False
1  2  8    True
2  3  7   False
3  4  6    True


There are other columns in the dataframe.  Does everything work starting with the right side of solution 2 beginning with df1['A','B'] .merge(df2['A', 'B'], ...)?

Yes, then better use a variable: cols = ['A', 'B] ; df1[cols].merge(df2[cols], how='left', ...) or with the keyword on

Thank you for this.  I have to say, I don't think I would have ever been able to figure this out from the Pandas documentation or command reference directly.   Is there some way to understand how Pandas is structured, that makes this more obvious?

Unfortunately, I think the key is to use enough the library to have an idea of the main commands and when to use them. The official documentation is a good start, but in the end you need the practice.
